# Source of Guru Ashtakam

Tags: scripture, history, adi-shankaracharya

Guru Ashtakam is a hymn said to be composed by Adi Shankaracharya. Can it be traced back to any of the texts written by him?

Comment: It is not necessary that it should be traced back to other text.

Comment: In that case, if it is a text unto itself, we should be able to trace down the Guru Ashtakam text itself :)

Comment: @Pandya It could have been passed down by oral traditions :)

Comment: What do you mean by "trace back" to texts wriiten by him?

Comment: @Rickross Funny you! If I knew that a stotram is from a scripture, I would not need to ask that question.

Comment: @Rickross It need not be part of a scripture, but could be found in a text written by him as the question asks.

Comment: Ok..Does not make too much of sense to me even them..anyways clearing my comments now..

Comment: @AmitSaxena the problem actually has to do with my bad habbit of  not reading forum posts attentively..Since u asked for source(in the title) i immediately assumed that u are talking about Scriptures..also ur Q is tagged with Scriptures..

Comment: @Rickross Thats okay, in my mind, any text written by Adi Shankara is also a scripture, hence the tag.

Comment: @AmitSaxena I don't think calling them Scriptures is  right in the strict sense..In any case [here](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/Adi%20Sankara's%20works.html) is Adi Shankara's works..So,i don't think there is any "Text" as such of which this stotra is a part of...

Comment: @Rickross I know you do not believe in Gurus, but Adi Shankara was a Guru or an enlightened master. Hence, anything he said or wrote was a scripture.

Comment: @AmitSaxena Haha i did u came to such a conclusion?..I myself have two Gurus..Guru's importance is supreme in spiritual progress..One who views Guru and Deity differently can't get true knowledge..BTw do u have Guru Diksha?..And also Shankara was a great Guru without doubt..but by Scriptures we only mean Vedas,Upanishads,Vedangas,Smritis,Puranas,Itihasas,Agamas etc..

Comment: @Amit Saxena Also u can check the kamakoti link i have given. Adi Shankara's works are not categorized into "Texts" as such..So,there can not be any answer possible for ur Q it seems..

Comment: @Rickross Oh, I remember you commenting negatively about some other Gurus. What do you mean 'we' only mean Vedas, who is we? :P Anyways, on a serious note, I respect your opinion but do not prescribe to it in this context.

Comment: @AmitSaxena Which Guru?Can u be specific?I'm not one of those who have disrespect for saints ,Gurus and Scriptures..We means Hindus..For Hindus these are the Scriptures and everything else is not just scriptures but they can be of immense value too..Also chk the link..

Comment: @Rickross lol I am a Hindu and I dont agree with that. Yeapp, checked the link. Why is it so important to you whether I have a been initiated or not? :)

Comment: @AmitSaxena Also if u find that post where i'm speaking ill of a Guru then pls do share it with me..I am very keen to know that..

Comment: @AmitSaxena Also Adi Shankara's works are "commentaries on Scriptures"..they are not Scriptures by themselves..Forgot to add this in earlier comment..